# Not able to clear History using applescript in El Capitan OSX

Tags: applescript, osx-elcapitan

I have been using below script to clear the safari history from selenium test in Yosemite OSX.  I have upgraded the OS to El Capitan and now the script wont work.

Error returned : Can't get "Clear History" button

Any help on this please.

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
 tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Safari"
    tell menu bar 1
        tell menu bar item "History"
            tell menu 1
                click menu item "Clear History…"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 1 -- optional
    click button "Clear History"
  end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
tell application "Safari" to activate  
set frontmost to true  
tell application "System Events"  
    tell process "Safari"  
        set frontmost to true  
        click menu item "Clear History…" of menu "History" of menu bar 1  
        delay 3  
        click button "Clear History" of sheet 1 of window 1  
    end tell  
end tell  
tell application "Safari" to quit
```